# Can we call method in implementation class not defined in its interface using interface variable?

Tags: c#, oop

Is it possible to call a method in implementation class of an interface which is not defined in interface using interface variable like below:

```
interface ILookup {
            public void someInterfaceMethod1();
            public void someInterfaceMethod2();
}
```

...and implementation class:

```
public class extendedLookUpImplementor: ILookup
{
          //constructor
          LookUpImplementor(){
          }

          public void someInterfaceMethod1(){
           // Implementation Code here.
          }

          public void someInterfaceMethod2(){
           // Implementation Code here.
          }

          public void ExtendedMethod(){
           // Implementation Code here.
          }

}
```

In client code:

```
ILookup lookupVar = new LookUpImplementor();
lookupVar -> someInterfaceMethod1(); // i know it will work.
lookupVar -> someInterfaceMethod2(); // i know it will work.
```

My question is, can i call ExtendedMethod using lookupVar like below:

```
lookupVar -> ExtendedMethod(); // Note again that ExtendedMethod() is not defined in Ilookup interface/contract.
```

Comment: I think that in c# you call methods like `object.Method()` and here you are implementing not extending (just a note)

Comment: No because `lookupVar` is of type `ILookup `.

Comment: I've been thinking about your question, maybe you're finding a way to extend the interface `ILookup`?

Answer (score 3):

Only by casting lookupVar as extendedLookUpImplementor, or by reflection I think.

Comment: Or via reflection, or using `dynamic`, but if you have a compile-time reference to the derived type, then definitely casting is the way to go. If you don't have a compile-time reference, then perhaps consider a change of design and only go the reflection/`dynamic` route if absolutely necessary.

Comment: I realised the reflection possibility just after posting and have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all as Ian1971 said, yes you can by casting it to specific type, say

```
ILookup lookupVar = new LookUpImplementor();
((extendedLookUpImplementor)lookupVar).ExtendedMethod(); //this should work
```

or alternatively using dynamic/reflection.

Having said that, I really really don't think this is a good way to do this because it would violate one of the objective of contract/interface.

For instance, if we have ILookup variable "lookupVar"

```
dynamic lookup = lookupVar;
lookup.ExtendedMethod(); //this would work
```

At any point in time, the code utilizing the object lookupVar does not guarantee that there would be a method ExtendedMethod and can throw on Exception on run time.

My real question to you would be, why you want to add a method that cannot be added in contract, what is your objective here. If the method is extending the class, try going through [C# extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) as they might fit in your scenario.

Comment: Great thanks Adil, your answer is detailed and helped me alot. Why i asked this question is mentioned below and adds little more information to why OR from where this question came into my mind.

Comment: I was using program in which interfaces are compiled in separate layer not changeable.Therefore, i need to implement interfaceand also extend functionality without changing interface. For some good reasons, I also want to continue to call the implementation-class using same interface from client / calling-program (as i do not want to make new interface and make changes in several places of client-program). Therefore, i wanted previous code in client-program to continue to work with implemented functions while same interface-variable can be used to call extended-function.

Comment: I tried with DI class and it worked too.